# Cast: functions fun1 and fun2 should the same value but the output is different. Can you explain why is it so?

Tags: c, long-long

It seems like the functions `fun1` and `fun2` should return the same values but the outputs are different. Can you explain why is it so?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long long fun1(int, int, int );
long long fun2(int, int, int );
int main(){
    int l = 1039, b = 3749, h =8473;
   cout<<"Volume is equal to "<<fun1(l,b,h)<<endl;
   cout<<"Volume is equal to "<<fun2(l,b,h)<<endl;
}

long long fun1(int length, int breadth, int height){
    long long volume = length * breadth * height;
    return volume;
}
long long fun2(int length, int breadth, int height){
    return (long long)length * breadth * height;
}
```

output:

```
Volume is equal to -1355615565
Volume is equal to 33004122803
```

Comment: You should add the language. It is pretty obvious it is C but without any tags people have very little chance to bump in your question.

Answer (score 1):

#### First case:

You are calculating everything in `int` type, and then casting to `long long`. Unfortunately the result is too big to fit in an `int`, so you have an overflow. Even if you cast it to a bigger type, that is too late, the overflow has already occured.

#### Second case:

You are casting to `long long` before actually doing the calculation. Thus, the calculation will be done using implicit conversion from `int` to `long long` and the result does fit in your container (which is `long long` now)… No overflow, life is beautiful!